# 'NSInvalidArgumentException' testViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I trying to bind the Json parse data with table view using below code and getting exception. I am using ASIHttpRequest and Json as well.

```
**Error details:**
webservice[2864:f803] 
*** 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[testViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6ecc4e0' 
***
```

---

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];


SBJsonParser *parser=[[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
NSDictionary *obj=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
obj=[parser objectWithString:responseString error:nil];

return obj.count;
```

---

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
SBJsonParser *parser=[[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
NSDictionary *obj=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
obj=[parser objectWithString:responseString error:nil];

NSMutableArray *statuses = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (NSDictionary *status in obj)
{

    [statuses addObject:status];


}
self.listdata=statuses;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"myCell"];    
if (cell == nil) {
    cell =  [[ UITableViewCell alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
cell.textLabel.text = [listdata objectAtIndex:row];

return cell;
```

Comment: Is your first error code for `numberOfRowsInSection`? IF yes just put `NsLog` to see **obj.count** if you are not geting it something that you dont expect.

Comment: I think you must be receiving some more description for the error in the logs

Comment: Please copy the exact, complete error message into your question.

Comment: webservice[2864:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[testViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6ecc4e0'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your table view data source is not implementing the method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`